# Preventing an Oauth provider spoof your account

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, oauth, twitter-oauth

For example:
OAuth providers like Google, Twitter, Facebook spoof you and start modifying your account/posting, sending out emails/messages without your permission. If that is the case, is there a way to prevent them from doing that?

Comment: Try looking at [security.se] for an answer or possibly post there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.